# Prove B is a proper subset of A

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Let $A=\{m \in \mathbb{Z} \mid m=4 a+3$ for some integer $a\}$ and let $B=\{n \in \mathbb{Z} \mid n=12 b+7$ for some integer $b\}$. Prove that $B \subset A$

Hey Guys!

I'm revising for an exam and encountered the problem above I'm just wondering if this is a valid way of solving this problem:

**Subset proof:**
\begin{align}
12b+7 &= 4a+3\\
4(3b+1)+3 &= 4a+3
\end{align}

Take $a$ to be $(3b+1)$

Therefore, $4a+3=4a+3$

Hence $B \subseteq A$

**Proper subset proof:**
\begin{align}
4(0)+3 &= 3\\
12(0)+7 &= 7\\
12(-1)+7 &= -5
\end{align}
Therefore, as the domain of $m$ is $> 7$ and $< -5$, it cannot produce the element $3$

Hence $B \subset A$.

Thanks so much for your help! Sorry if this question seems a bit rushed, I don't have much time to spare, thanks!

Comment: The  "proof" is a pile of bones with no connective tissue: No quantifiers,  no "$\implies$" and hence no clear explanation of  how the conclusion $B\subseteq A$ is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have it right. Your proof is correct but  it may be polished if you wish.

You just need one counter example for the proper subset part.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

Presentation wise:

Let $x \in B$, we can write

$$x=12b+7=4(3b+1)+3$$

where $b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

since $3b+1 \in \mathbb{Z}, x \in A$.

To prove that it is a proper subset.

Since $4(0)+3 =3$, we have $3 \in A$. However, we claim that $3 \notin B$. Suppose not,

$$12b+7=3$$

Then we have $$12b=-4 \iff 3b = -1$$ which is a contradiction.

Remark:

I have no idea what is domain of $m$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed. $\checkmark$.

You have shown that for every $n\in B$ that $n\in A$ but that the converse does not hold. Thus you have a proof that $ B\subsetneq A$, as required.

Smooth out the presentation and you will be done.